# List of Tuples in a function explained

Tags: python, list, tuples

Recently I started to learn Python for research, I come from JS, Frontend UI/UX Web development, so you can imagine all of this is a whole new concept for me.

I'm just entering to the world of data and Tuples it seems to be a very important concept in the data world that JS lacks the syntactic support for tuples, however it has `map` and `set` and manage access data with `const` and `let` that in my opinion, the support for tuples would enrich JS programming experience.

I'm very comfortable with Terminal and printing everything from the command line, I'm not liking at all Interactive mode or Jupyter, I think I lose control.

But today I ran into a **newbie problem**

Lets's start with this basic example, and I think this is what normally should print when we need a list of tuples:

```
## I will create a list of tuples
coordinates = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
for (x,y) in coordinates : 
    print(x,y)

## The Result:
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Now let's try a "*function*" example, **and here is my question:** 
The problem here is that the *`return`* is only giving us one tuple and in tuple type not in list :

```
import random

def AllX() :  
    low = 10
    high = 90
    mini = 20
    maxi = 50

    coordinates = [(random.randint(low, high), random.randint(mini, maxi)) for k in range(10)]

    coordinates += [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

    for (x,y) in coordinates :
        # run = x,y
        return (x,y)

print(AllX())

## The Result:
(79, 45)
```

If I use *`print`* instead of *`return`* I will get the next result :

```
## The Result:

76 28
11 49
60 23
78 33
49 44
77 46
56 45
31 25
17 23
53 22
None
```

But that won't be what we really expected, we need a list and because (just like random example) if we want to use this function in other situations, we needed to return the list.

And another thing that is questioning me my understanding of the logic of listing tuples, or even loops, is that if we use the same function but let's try to loop the same function with *`return`*:

```
generator = AllX()

for item in generator :
    print(item)
```

The Result will return only 2 numbers that belong to a random tuple:

```
## The Result:

27
33
```

hope someone can give me some guidance or explanation on why/how this is happening in `return` and why if we want to iterate the same function the result is like that

Comment: actually your question is too much lengthy, can you please tell me what is the expected output.

Comment: Your problem is  `return (x,y)` return on the first coordinate (i.e. you don't finish the for loop).  If you want to return coordinate you can just use `return coordinates`.

Comment: your expected output is result 1 or result 2, `result 1= [(14, 38), (74, 48), (70, 25), (83, 27), (69, 23), (13, 49), (67, 21), (78, 24), (72, 49), (80, 31), (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]`
`result 2 = [14, 74, 70, 83, 69, 13, 67, 78, 72, 80, 1, 3, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement immediately returns and exits the function. If you call return in a loop, it just returns the item in the loop and the loop won't go any futher.

```
def AllX() :  
    low = 10
    high = 90
    mini = 20
    maxi = 50

    coordinates = [(random.randint(low, high), random.randint(mini, maxi)) for k in range(10)]

    coordinates += [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
    return coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` list will give all X, and `coordinates` list will give both x and y.

```
import random
def AllX():
    low = 10
    high = 90
    mini = 20
    maxi = 50
    result = []
    coordinates = [(random.randint(low, high), random.randint(mini, maxi)) for k in range(10)]
    coordinates += [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
    print(coordinates)
    for (x,y) in coordinates:
        # run = x,y
        result.append(x)
    return result
print(AllX())
```